# Something wrong with my Array's IndexPath? swift 4 Firebase

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm not sure how to describe my problem propperly but here is what is going wrong.

So i have a TableView populated with `posts` that users upload, but know i want to enable my users to comment on each others posts in the way that when they click A post then they are presented with a new ViewController that contains Data from only the post they clicked. that i have managed so thats not the problem. But the problem is that when they click a indexPath what ever it is, It is allways the same index That is Clicked. so for example if there are 3 posts and that's named `test 1`, `test 2` and `test 3` then what ever post they click it is allways the latest post that is presented so in this case it would always be `test 3` that is presented. So how are they presented with the new viewController? All the `posts` are uploaded and Stored with the an Auto Generated Id Generated by FirebaseDatabase.

so i'm using this code to get the AutoGenerated Id and pass it to a variable that is global and pass it to the `DetailViewController`:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let post = posts[indexPath.row]
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "CommentSegue", sender: post)

    Database.database().reference().child("posts").observe( .value) { (snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            postsKey = key
        }
    }
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "CommentSegue"{
        let commentVC = segue.destination as! CommentViewController
        commentVC.post = (sender as? NSDictionary?)!
    }
}
```

I'm Using exactly this method to delete posts and that is working perfectly fine but this only is not, So may there be a problem how i'm trying to send the data or maybe i'm appending the post the wrong way to the posts array.

and it looks like this in the CommentViewController:

```
import UIKit
import FirebaseDatabase
import FirebaseStorage
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseCore
import Firebase

class CommentViewController: UIViewController {

var post: NSDictionary?

//  var comments: [NSDictionary] = []


let postKey = postsKey
@IBOutlet weak var titeLabel: UILabel!




override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    loadData()


}



func loadData() {
        print(postKey)
        Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
            if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                self.titeLabel.text = dict["title"] as? String


        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, using the `sender` might be confusing; typically sender would be the one who caused the event, not an arbitrary data being transported.

I would improve your code using this:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    performSegue(withIdentifier: "CommentSegue", sender: tableView)
    // ...
}

override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

    if segue.identifier == "CommentSegue"{
        guard let commentVC = segue.destination as? CommentViewController else { return }
        guard let tableView = sender as? UITableView else { return }
        guard let selectedRow = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow?.row else { return }

        let post =  posts[selectedRow]
        print("Selected: \(post)")
        commentVC.post = post
    }
}
```

Now, check if `post` in `prepare(for:sender:)` has the correct value (which it should) according to the pressed row (watch the output of the print statement)

If `post` is correct all the time, maybe the `CommentViewController` does not update the UI correcly (maybe only at the first time), so check the `viewDidLoad` / `viewDidAppear` function in there. Maybe you should also post the code of it here.

**Update**

I think you need to get the database key of the post from the provided `post` dictionary in the `CommentViewController`, maybe like this:

```
func loadData() {
    postKey = post["key"] // or something else, you'll need to fetch the data base key from the current dictionary
    Database.database().reference().child("posts").child(postKey).observeSingleEvent(of: .value) { (snapshot) in
        if let dict = snapshot.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
            self.titeLabel.text = dict["title"] as? String
    }
}
```

Comment: Also i'm not sure what you are doing with the postKey, but you mention that you are using it as a global variable for your `DetailViewContoller`.  While I don't like the use of global vars, you really need to check for a race condition as well.  You should place your `performSegue(...)` inside of the database call closure(complete handle).  Currently your segue is firing before your database call is returned, while you are storing the passed information into global, i'm thinking the UI is laid out before the database response is processed.

Comment: @JacobBoyd i have updated the my question and now shows what it looks like in the CommentViewController.   @AndreasOetjen your code works perfect the `postKey` is they correct index now but still in the CommentViewController it is showing only `test 3` but in the console i'm printing the `postKey` and it is printing the correct index

Comment: So, what are you doing with `post` in the `DetailViewController`? What is `postKey` or `postsKey`?  See my modified anser above.

Comment: Then you should mark the answer as "answered", in order to show anyone in the future that this solves your problem.

Comment: could you please check this question out i think you could possible help me with this one to. thanks.[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48241086/allowing-specefic-users-to-delete-post-swift-4-firebase]